# Making delayed::job tasks run immediately in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

How do I configure Delayed::Job to run all delayed methods immediately in development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `config/environment.rb` add

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false if Rails.env.development?
```